# How to access a lamp server in lan using public ip

Tags: ip, lamp

I have a LAMP server. It works great if I access using the private ip e.g. 192.168... I also did port forwarding to access to it using its public ip and it works great if I'm not in the same LAN as the server, so if I use mobile data, I can access to it, but if I'm with my laptop which is connected to the same router, I can't.

How can I access to a lamp server using the public ip and being in the same LAN? I've read about creating a DNS server but I think that's too complex for this and there must be an easier answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is NAT hair-pinning on the router. Presently Cisco routers support it.

You may also create a DNS host-entry on your PC which points the public IP(or DNS name) to local IP.

> If two hosts (called X1 and X2) are behind the same NAT and exchanging traffic, the NAT may allocate an address on the outside of the NAT for X2, called X2':x2'.  If X1 sends traffic to X2':x2', it goes to the NAT, which must relay the traffic
> from X1 to X2.  This is referred to as hairpinning. [Source](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5128#section-2.10)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried editing /etc/hosts but I realized something: in my laptop I modified that file as follows: public IP DNS name and it works at home! but if I go to the university and use its network, it would work... In addition to that, modifying hosts doesn't work well with owncloud client (The server is for owncloud). thank you again!